# How do I obtain a list of all of the pages within an asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reflection

How do I obtain a list of all of the pages within an asp.net mvc project for use in a dropdown list.

I'd also like to obtain a list of all of the controls within that page.

The problem is that I'd be calling this from a different project in the same solution.

Can i use reflection for this????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection to look at the classes in an assembly and see if they inherit from System.Web.UI.Page which would indicate if its a page.  I'd look at the directory of the project(s) using a DirectoryInfo object and just filter the selection by the extension ".aspx"

Comment: What about the controls within that page??

Comment: I'm confused about the controls...MVC doesn't have web controls like web forms.  If you are using web forms you can parse the designer.vb file for each page.

Comment: Nop., I'm using MVC, I meant regular controls, like HTML textbox and HTML Dropdowns, etc... Basically MVC uses helper methods to generate the markup, I guess I could parse those helper methods

Comment: That seems to be a valid approach because I'm assuming there is a one to one relationship between the helper methods and the controls they generate...?